# What is happening when pandas.Series converts int64s into NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, series

I have a csv with dates and integers (Headers: Date, Number), separated by a tab.

I'm trying to create a calendar heatmap with [CalMap](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap) (demo on that page). The function that creates the chart takes data that's indexed by DateTime.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",delimiter="\t")
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

events = pd.Series(df['Date'],index = df['Number'])
calmap.yearplot(events)
```

But when I check `events.head(5)`, it gives the date followed by NaN. I check `df['Number'].head(5)` and they appear as int64.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this conversion?

Edit: Data below

```
Date    Number
7/9/2018    40
7/10/2018   40
7/11/2018   40
7/12/2018   70
7/13/2018   30
```

Edit: Output of events.head(5)

```
2018-07-09   NaN
2018-07-10   NaN
2018-07-11   NaN
2018-07-12   NaN
2018-07-13   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: For a [example] it would help to post the first five rows (six if headers) of `data.csv`.

Comment: Thank you @Amadan, I'm still learning the etiquette of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not `NaN`, it is [`NaT`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes) (Not a Timestamp), which is unique to Pandas, though Pandas makes it compatible with NaN, and uses it similarly to NaN in floating-point columns to mark missing data.

What `pd.Series(data, index=index)` does apparently depends on the type of `data`. If `data` is a list, then `index` has to be of equal length, and a new `Series` will be constructed, with `data` being data, and `index` being index. However, if `data` is already a `Series` (such as `df['Date']`), it will instead take the rows corresponding to `index` and construct a new `Series` out of those rows. For example:

```
pd.Series(df['Date'], [1, 1, 4])
```

will give you

```
1   2018-07-10
1   2018-07-10
4   2018-07-13
```

Where `2018-07-10` comes from row #1, and `2018-07-11` from row #4 of `df['Date']`. However, there is no row with index `40`, `70` or `30` in your sample input data, so missing data is presumed, and `NaT` is inserted instead.

In contrast, this is what you get when you use a list instead:

```
pd.Series(df['Date'].to_list(), index=df['Number'])
# => Number
#    40   2018-07-09
#    40   2018-07-10
#    40   2018-07-11
#    70   2018-07-12
#    30   2018-07-13
#    dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in my output, it specifically states NaN. Perhaps another issue is arising? I will put the output as an edit in the original question.

Comment: @Toblor: Huh, weird. Maybe it's a version difference then.

Comment: I believe I've figured it out. You lead me in the right direction of manipulating the series into a list, so I converted both `df['Date']` and `df['Number']` to a list, which worked for my code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the series into lists via `df['Date'].tolist()` and `df['Number'].tolist()`. `calmap.calendarplot(events)` was able to accept these instead of the original parameters as series.